Exporting function and interface not wroking
I am exporting a function and type from library from convertToUpper.ts file.
export function Sample() {
  console.log('sample')
}

export type IProp = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

In my lib index.ts look like this:
export { IProp, Sample } from './helpers/convertToUpper' exporting both.
when I try to import like:
import {ConvertToUpper, IProp } from "utils";
getting following error:
Module '"utils"' has no exported member 'ConvertToUpper'. Did you mean to use 'import ConvertToUpper from "utils"' instead?ts(2614)


Where are you exporting ConvertToUpper from? And why exporting twice, first while declaration and then again using export {...}?

@Sahiljangra - I am exporting from react library to react app

I feel some info is missing. If you can provide more details...

@Sahiljangra - it is react library. when I change the extension from ts to tsx it works fine. But I am just exporting functions and interfaces. look to avoid tsx and preferring ts. need any config change in react-lib - ?

Probably because ConvertToUpper is exported with default keyword, in that case you have to use a default import ConvertToUpper (syntax: import ConvertToUpper from 'utils' with no curly braces), if that's the answer, then you should probably read error messages before asking.

After gone through number of articles, I changed the "main" from "index.tsx" to "index.ts" works now. thanks every one
